# JMS deserialize part of an xml

Tags: php, xml, serialization, jms-serializer

I am trying to deserialize a complicated xml, and I only need a nested part of the xml not the whole part.

There is a simple example, what I'd like to do:

```xml
<foo>
  <bar>
    <user>
      <name>John Doe</name>
      <age>28</age>
    </user>
  <bar>
<foo>
```

```php
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;


/**
 * @JMS\XmlRoot("user")
 */
class User
{
    private string $name;

    private int $age;
}
```

I don't want to add the `Foo` and `Bar` classes if it's not necessary, because I only need the `User` object.

```php
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;

$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$user = $serializer->deserialize($xml, User::class, 'xml');
```

If I try to deserialize the xml, the object will be empty.

Is there any solution in `jms\serializer`?